# About Database helper

Tags: android, android-ndk

I have a database helper class

```
private static class DatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper{
        DatabaseHelper(Context context){
            super(context,DATABASE_NAME,null,DATABASE_VERSION);
        }
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db){
            db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }
        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db,int oldVersion,int newVersion){
            Log.w(TAG, "Upgrading database from version " + oldVersion + "to" + newVersion + ", which will destroy all old data");
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS titles");
            onCreate(db);
        }
    }
```

on my project, I need to create a new object of this DatabaseHelper like DatabaseHelper aa = new DatabaseHelper(context). If that will execute  db.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE); every time when my program start? This line is for creating a new database;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No it will not be called every time. About the open helper and the code you postet you need to know 2 things:

1. OnCreate will only called once (when your database is first created). Then (as long as your database exists) this code will never be called again.
   since you call manually onCreate() in your onUpgrade (which I wouldnt recommend):
2. In your super constructor you parse a Database version. This version is stored by the helper and as long this version stays same the onUpgrade will not be called.
   2.

Answer (score 2):

It will run onCreate during the creation of the DatabaseHelper if the database does not exists, and it will run onUpgrade if the database exists and was created with a lower DATABASE_VERSION

Answer (score 0):

The proper way of defining DB adapter is like below. I use it in many projects.

The usage is:

- in onCreate():

```
    mDB = new DBAdapter(this); 
    mDB.open();
```

- in onDestroy():

```
    mDB.close();
    mDB = null;
```

- and the DB Adapter class:

  ```
  package ....


     /**
      * The internal database adapter
      * @author Yar
      */

      public class DBAdapter {
  private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "....";
  private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

  private static final String TABLE_SOMETHING = "something_tab";

  // Columns names definitions:        
  public static final String COL_ID = "id";         //key
  public static final String COL_NAME = "name";

  private SQLiteDatabase mDb;
  private DBOpenHelper mDbHelper;


  public DBAdapter(Context pContext) {        
      mDbHelper = new DBOpenHelper(pContext, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
  }

  /**
  * Close the database
  */
  public void close() {
      mDb.close();
  }

  /**
   * Open the database, create if not found
   * @throws SQLiteException
   */
  public void open() throws SQLiteException {
      mDb = mDbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
  }



  ....... functions getting / setting data from database




  /**
   * The DB helper class
   * @author Yar
   */    
  private static class DBOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

      public DBOpenHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory, int version) {
          super(context, name, factory, version);
      }

      // SQL Statements to create a new database.
      private static final String TABLE_SOMETHING_CREATE = 
          "create table "+TABLE_SOMETHING+" ("+COL_ID+" integer primary key autoincrement, "+
                                               COL_NAME+" text not null); ";  

      @Override
      public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase pDb) {
          pDb.execSQL(TABLE_SOMETHING_CREATE);  
      }

      @Override
      public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase pDb, int pOldVersion, int pNewVersion) {
          // Drop the old table.
          pDb.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_SOMETHING);
          // Create a new one.
          onCreate(pDb);            
      }
  }
  ```

  }